# Gamma square function in R?

Tags: r

Does anyone have idea  how to write gamma^2(1+/beta)?
I'm right if  I used gamma(1+/beta)*gamma(1+/beta)?. Any idea or suggestion?
Thanks for helping
[image]

Comment: That notation could mean anything. It could be a square; it could be a superscript. I would look where you found that equation for context.

Comment: Thanks. The equation is for  Weibull Variance. Or the Weibull distribution with three paramters. Here is the link for the equation. https://creprep.wordpress.com/2014/01/24/calculate-weibull-mean-and-variance/

Comment: This means I could use gamma(1+1/beta)*gamma(1+1/beta) ??

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution -- the notation they use for Weibull variance makes the meaning much more clear in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. I think in wikipedia the notation is for two parameter Weibull distribution. I want to calculate the expected variance Var(Y) and Mean E(Y) for three paramter Weibull distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Gamma square `(x)` is just `Gamma(x)*Gamma(x)`

The MLE estimates for `Weibull` distribution:

```
SDcap =  11.4982087*((gamma(1+(2/1.1326673))-(gamma(1+(1/1.1326673)))^2))^0.5
```

where `γ = Weibull`, `Shape = 1.1326673`, `α = Weibull`, `Scale = 11.4982087`